# Docusign automatically select template and Recipient and send the document

Tags: docusignapi

We are planning to add docusign to our salesforce instance. we are currently analyzing to have a button on the detail page of Opportunity or any object on click of the button, selection of the template and recipient takes place automatically from the code and send the document. we don't want any middle page where user manually select the template and recipient. please let me know how can we achieve this in docusign app exchange.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by creating a Custom Button that provides such parameters to DocuSign.  Specifically, you can specify signer information, a list of templates to use, and tell DocuSign that it should send the envelope without showing that editing page.

This section of the DocuSign for Salesforce Administrator Guide has all the details:  https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-admin-guide/admin-guide/custom-buttons

The parameters you can look for are DST for DocuSign templates; CCRM, CCTM, and CRL for specifying recipients; and OCO for setting one-click options:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

var DST='FBB2E4E8-A1B6-40C5-8B00-2AB31512DF04';
var CRL='Email~dfssigner@mailinator.com;LastName~Test Signer';
var OCO='Send';

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&DST="+DST+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO;
```

Comment: Below are the issues that i get during the above implementation

    Envelope could not be created.
    Please contact DocuSign Support. Email to: service@docusign.com.
    Error: System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx